# Set a variable in django settings conditional to if dockerized

Tags: python, django, docker

I am building a Django site that may be deployed at several sites, some dockerized, some not.

In the Django settings.py file there is a setting that may change depending on the host (IP address) variable and more particularly if run from within a Docker Container.

Particularly, Docker use this [special DNS name](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/) (host.docker.internal) to refer to the host computer localhost from within a docker container, where using localhost only in a container refer to the docker instance localhost instead.

For example the following case would be use by Django to connect to a SQL instance. Django is dockerized and the database is on the host server :

```
'HOST': 'host.docker.internal'
```

where in another case, Django is not run in a docker container, just on the host, so it can directly access the database locally:

```
'HOST': 'localhost'
```

**Question:** Would there be a way to make a conditional statement before such an environment variable would be required, such as:

```
if in_docker:
    HOST = 'host.docker.internal'
else:
    HOST = 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environment variable for that:

```
import os
HOST = os.environ.get('HOST_URL', 'localhost')
```

And inside `Dockerfile`, set a environment variable

```
ENV HOST_URL host.docker.internal
```

More information can be found in [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement).